# I am trying to create a list of div boxes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a list of div boxes however, when I place them the second image is not flush with the left side of the container.

I would like to add space between the two divs use a border to create a line between news articles. If you know how to make this work please leave a comment. 
The page simply does nothing. Its not accepting ANY style commands at all.

I did not include any other style code because this is the only working style code. To be honest I could delete the wrap2 style and nothing would change.

```css
img.wrap {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 10px 20px;
}
img.wrap2 {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="invisiblebox">
  <div id="nvidiablog1">
    <a href="https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2016/11/26/virtual-reality-flight-simluation/">
      <img src="images/virtual.jpg" class="wrap" height="100" width="100">
    </a>
    <p>According to a recent article posted by NVIDIA, Mass Virtual has been a long standing partner of the United States Navy. Mass Virtual's specialty is to provide the Navy with virtual reality training simulators, and boy did they deliver. Mass Virtual's
      newest training simulator which, to quote the article written by John Chaney <i>"is beyond visual range"</i>. To read more about this article please click the image to be redirected.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="nvidiablog2">
    <a href="https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2016/11/28/titan-supercomputer-ethanol/">
      <img src="images/titan.jpg" class="wrap2" height="100" width="100">
    </a>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if its not "accepting" any styleing, please use ctrl + f5 to refresh

Comment: Are you trying this https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/pf6f3uqx/1/

Comment: I fixed the issue by creating an unordered list. I can not figure out how to delete this question though just know that my issue is resolved.

Comment: Click the "delete" under the question

Comment: @mplungjan i think you can help him to delete this quetion

Comment: @dreamhunter - actually not. I do not have the delete link until the question is closed and then it is only a delete vote

Comment: ok,but we can't flag this question for close because other moderators may decline that

Comment: We can close as "other"

Answer (score 0):

.container{display:flex;}

And remove float